# How to creating recursive JSON hierarchy tree?

Tags: python, pandas

You can see the name of parent is color start with child_id 0
and children is red and blue that binds id from color.

I like to get the data in the table to make it into Json how to do?

[image]

My data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': ['2', '13', '14', '15'],
    'name': ['color', 'red', 'blue', 'ruby red'],
    'child_id': ['0', '2', '2', '13']
}
  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Expected Output

```
[
    {
        "name": "color",
        "id": 2,
        "child_id": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "red",
                "id": 13,
                "child_id": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "ruby red",
                        "id": 15,
                        "child_id": 13,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "blue",
                "id": 14,
                "child_id": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider it as a tree and apply simple traversal on the dictionary, which is converted from df by `df.to_dict()`. Type annotations are added. Hope you can understand.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List, Dict, Optional
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


@dataclass
class Tree:
    name: str
    id: int
    child_id: int
    children: List['Tree'] = field(default_factory=list)


def traversal(df: DataFrame) -> Optional[Tree]:
    tmp: List[Tree] = [Tree(name=i["name"], id=int(i["id"]), child_id=int(i["child_id"])) for i in df.to_dict("records")]
    memo: Dict[int, Tree] = {i.id: i for i in tmp}
    root = None
    for i in tmp:
        if i.child_id == 0:
            root = i
        else:
            memo[i.child_id].children.append(i)
    return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {
        'id': ['2', '13', '14', '15'],
        'name': ['color', 'red', 'blue', 'ruby red'],
        'child_id': ['0', '2', '2', '13']
    }
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
    res = traversal(dataframe)
    if res:
        pprint([asdict(res)])
    else:
        print("err")
```

Output:

```
[{'child_id': 0,
  'children': [{'child_id': 2,
                'children': [{'child_id': 13,
                              'children': [],
                              'id': 15,
                              'name': 'ruby red'}],
                'id': 13,
                'name': 'red'},
               {'child_id': 2, 'children': [], 'id': 14, 'name': 'blue'}],
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'color'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try to understand.